# Cannot initialize a Javascript Object properly

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an array of objects using another array as input.  I have the following code for the loop:

```
    // Setup product key for local items
    for (var i=0; i<$scope.listDetails.details.length ; i++) {
        if ($scope.listDetails.details[i].productIdentifier2 == 'Local') {
            var productFound = false;
            for (var j=0; j< $scope.allproducts.length ; j++) {
                if ($scope.listDetails.details[i].category == $scope.allproducts[j].category && $scope.listDetails.details[i].productname == $scope.allproducts[j].productname && $scope.listDetails.details[i].productIdentifier2 == $scope.allproducts[j].productIdentifier2) {
                    $scope.listDetails.details[i].productKey = $scope.allproducts[j].productKey;
                    productFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Group all products to be inserted
            if (productFound==false) {
                var productDetailSingle = {};
                console.log("productDetail init");
                console.log(productDetailSingle);
                productDetailSingle.category = $scope.listDetails.details[i].cateogry;
                productDetailSingle.itemStatus = $scope.listDetails.details[i].itemStatus;
                productDetailSingle.productIdentifier1 = $scope.listDetails.details[i].productcode;
                productDetailSingle.productIdentifier2 = $scope.listDetails.details[i].productIdentifier2;
                productDetailSingle.productName = $scope.listDetails.details[i].productname;
                productDetailSingle.productname = $scope.listDetails.details[i].productname;
                productDetailSingle.productcode = $scope.listDetails.details[i].productcode;
                console.log("productDetail push");
                console.log(productDetailSingle);
                productsToAdd.push(productDetailSingle);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem I am having is that when I log the productDetailSingle object, I am getting other properties that I did not initialize.  Here's the output for the console log for the condition if (productFound==false):

```
[Log] productDetail init (console-via-logger.js, line 173)
[Log] {} (console-via-logger.js, line 173)
[Log] productDetail push (console-via-logger.js, line 173)
[Log] Object (console-via-logger.js, line 173)

category: undefined
itemStatus: "OPEN"
productIdentifier1: 0
productIdentifier2: "Local"
productName: "mushroom "
productcode: 0
productname: "mushroom "

Object Prototype

[Log] productDetail init (console-via-logger.js, line 173)
[Log] {} (console-via-logger.js, line 173)
[Log] productDetail push (console-via-logger.js, line 173)
[Log] Object (console-via-logger.js, line 173)

available: "Y"
category: undefined
itemStatus: "OPEN"
price: null
productDesc: null
productIdentifier1: 0
productIdentifier2: "Local"
productKey: 53
productName: "nido milk"
productcode: 0
productname: "nido milk"
uuid: "BAAFE64E-CF76-4156-A09F-80F678E3A2B0"
```

Object Prototype

As you can see, the first object has been initialized correctly.  However, for the second object, although I initially set it to {}, there were other properties that has been added to the second object.  Does anyone encountered this type of problem before?

Comment: you have a typo in `$scope.listDetails.details[i].cateogry;`

Answer (score 0):

Use function programming for this...

```
const productsToAdd = $scope.listDetails.details
  .filter(detail => detail.productIdentifier2 === 'local')
  .map(detail => {
    const productKey = $scope.allproducts
      .filter(product => (detail.category && detail.productName === product.productName && detail.productIdentifier2 === product.productIdentifier2))
      .map(product => product.productKey)
      .reduce((memo, productKey) => productKey, false);

    if(!productKey) {
      return {
        category: detail.category,
        itemStatus: detail.itemStatus,
        productIdentifier1: detail.productIdentifier1,
        productIdentifier2: detail.productIdentifier2,
        productName: detail.productName,
        productcode: detail.productcode
      };
    } else {
      detail.productKey = productKey 
    }

    return false;
  })
   //remove the falses from above
  .filter(productToAdd => productToAdd);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I found the problem when I did the debug in Chrome.  It seems like the values being shown are the current values of the object instead of its value at the time the console.log was executed.